# extjs4 grid checkcolumn

Tags: checkbox, grid, extjs4

As we know, extjs4 provides a grid build-in checkcolumn, but seems this type only can bind with special bool type. My requirement is only want to show a checkbox in grid, don't want to bind to any field.

How can I achieve that?

Thanks

Comment: And may I as what is the purpose of only showing the checkbox and not binding it to a field?

Comment: yes, I just want to this column can let user select record, then do some operations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [CheckboxModel](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.selection.CheckboxModel) as a selection model for your grid. Basic usage:

```js
var grid2 = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    selModel: Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel'),
    // ...
});
```

See *"Framed with Checkbox Selection and Horizontal Scrolling"* example at [official examples page](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.1.0-gpl/examples/grid/grid-plugins.html).